# ¿Existe alguna forma de reducir el tamaño de este codigo?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en programación, estaba empezando con Python y se me ocurrió
hacer un programa que sacara el porcentaje de un numero de forma mas cómoda,
¿alguien me podría decir si hay alguna forma mas simple de escribir el código y tal vez así aprender algo nuevo?

```
percentage = float(input("Porcentaje: %"))
of = float(input("De: "))

try:
    if percentage == 1:
        print(of * 0.01)

    elif percentage == 2:
        print(of * 0.02)

    elif percentage == 3:
        print(of * 0.03)

    elif percentage == 4:
        print(of * 0.04)

    elif percentage == 5:
        print(of * 0.05)

    elif percentage == 6:
        print(of * 0.06)

    elif percentage == 7:
        print(of * 0.07)

    elif percentage == 8:
        print(of * 0.08)

    elif percentage == 9:
        print(of * 0.09)

    elif percentage == 10:
        print(of * 0.1)

except:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Hola O69person, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] No termino de entender por qué usas la estructura condicional ¿Si el porcentaje es mayor de 10 menor de 1 o no es entero no quieres que haga nada? ¿Por qué no simplemente aplicas `of * percentage / 100`?

Comment: Como @FJSevilla plantea, no necesitas realizar esa serie de comprobaciones. Lo ideal, ahora que estás aprendiendo es que escribas la fórmula que calcula el porcentaje de un número. Saludos

Comment: Se me habia olvidado por completo que se podian sacar porcentajes de esa forma, agradezco la ayuda, use la estructura condicional para hacerlo de forma mas comoda como dije, así, en vez de escribir 0,02 para sacar el 2% solo tendria que escribir 2, aunque pierde sentido al saber la formula que me haz dicho.

Comment: Si resolvieron tu duda, recuerda seleccionar la respuesta, para que esta pregunta se cierre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
percentage = float(input("Porcentaje: %"))
of = float(input("De: "))
try
   print(of * (percentage * 0.01))
except:
    print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta seria una buena forma

```
percentage = float(input("Porcentaje: %"))
of = float(input("De: "))

try:
    print(of * (percentage / 100))
except:
    print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Con lo que se puede interpetar de ese codigo (Quieres que sea un numero entre 1 y 10) creo que esto te servira.

```
percentage=float(input("Porcentaje: %"))
if percentage > 1 and percentage <= 10:
    of=float(input("De: "))
    print((percentage/100)*of)
else:
    print("Error")
```

Answer (score -2):

Si, puedes hacer un método que devuelva el valor que deseas, el cual llamaras y con un solo print lo mostraras por pantalla... También puedes coger el porcentaje e independientemente del número, ejecutas la fórmula del %, ya que siempre se obtendrá de la misma forma. Así eliminaras todos esos condicionales...